# Get users with item count <= 1 in sql

Tags: sql, postgresql

We have these tables in PostgreSQL 12:

```
User -> id, name, email
items -> id, user_id, description
```

We want to run a query to find users that have 1 item or less.

I tried using a join statement and in the WHERE clause tried to put the count of users < 1 with this query

```
select * from "user" inner join item on "user".id = item.user_id where count(item.user_id) < 1;
```

but it failed and gave me this error.

> ERROR:  aggregate functions are not allowed in WHERE
> LINE 1: ...inner join item on "user".id = item.user_id where count(item...

so im thinking the query needs to be more techincal.
Can anyone please help me with this? thanks

Comment: *item count < 1* - so that's basically zero then?

Comment: @Stu sorry i meant item count <= 1

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```
select u.*
from user u
left join (
  select user_id, count(*) as cnt from items group by user_id
) x on x.user_id = u.id
where x.cnt = 1 or x.cnt is null
```

Comment: `...where coalesce(x.cnt, 1) <= 1`

Answer (score 0):

You don't technically need a JOIN for this. You can get all the necessary data from the `item` table with `GROUP BY`. The trick is you need to use `HAVING` instead of `WHERE` for aggregated data like `COUNT()`

```
SELECT user_id
FROM item
GROUP BY user_id
HAVING COUNT(id) > 1
```

But we can add a `JOIN` if you want to see more fields from the `user` table:

```
SELECT u.id, u.name, u.email
FROM item i
INNER JOIN "user" u on u.id = i.user_id
GROUP BY u.id, u.name, u.email
HAVING COUNT(i.id) > 1
```

Comment: hey, this looks like it works! thanks. how do you modify the query here to check if those items have a specific value. e.g item_isbasic = 'true'? Thanks ALOT!

Comment: That depends on how they factor into the count